Transformation of function $f$ with continuous derivative to a form that preserves $\int_a^bg(f(x))$ for any continuous function $g$
I was trying to find a transformation $f$ to some continuous increasing function $F$, $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given constants $a$ and $b$   for any function with continuous derivative $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $$\int_a^bg(f(x))\,dx=\int_a^bg(F(x))\,dx$$ for any continuous function $g$.
My original idea was to have something like the continuous equivalent of ordering all the points in a continuous curve. I thought of the following function $F$:
$$F'(F^{-1}(x))=
\begin{cases}
 0, \exists t: f(t)=x,f'(t)=0 \\
      \left(\sum_{f(t)=x,a\leq x\leq b} \frac{1}{f'(t)}\right)^{-1} &\text{if}\ &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
The intuition is that $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ represents how "long" a function stays at that point. Edit: I noticed this definition does not work for curves with an interval of points such that $f'(x)=0$
I think that this transformation should also satisfy $$\max F'(x)\leq \max f'(x)$$ for all functions $f$ that are transformed to $F$, but I am again unable to prove this.
Does this "transformation" $F$ satisfy the properties I have stated above? If they do then how do I go about proving this or is there a counterexample. If $F$ does not satisfy this then do there exist transformations that satisfy the above properties?
PS: I am a high school student exploring a fun idea so I might not have used rigorous terminology above. Feel free to mention advanced topics as I am confident in my ability to read up.

It does not have to be the same transformation for all a and b

I forgot to include the requirement that F(x) has to be increasing, I will edit it in

I think that you came up with a cool problem. As you already conjecture, one way to ensure that
\begin{equation}\label{eq}\int_a^b g(f(x)) dx = \int_a^b g(F(x)) dx\end{equation}
is to "rearrange" f in an increasing fashion on the interval $[a,b]$. If you are interested in that, you can look into decreasing rearrangements. They are a tool from real analysis, which makes it easier to compare different functions to eachother.
And another remark: If one sets $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and interprets it as a probability space equipped with the uniform measure, then the functions f and F can be interpreted as random variables defined on that space. Then, your desired property follows, if both of these random variables are identically distributed. This is the reason why probabilists often only specify the distribution of the random variables they work with: It already determines the evaluation of all the observables, which in your example are the possible choices of g's.
By this probabilistic interpretation it also follows that assuming your desired equality for any continuous g actually implies that f and F are rearrangements of eachother, i.e., that they have the same distribution function. This is because the Fourier transform of a random variable uniquely determines it's law, see this wikipedia page for example.

Ah the decreasing rearrangement seems to be what I was trying to do. I also thought using an indicator function like approach originally but gave up on it. Does the inequality with the max of the derivative in the interval holds true?

Yes, the decreasing rearrangement 'reduces' the derivative. This is known as the Polya-Szego inequality, which estimates integrals/the maximum of the derivative of the decreasing rearrangement by the same integral/the maximum of the derivative of the original function.
